# Resolving a reduce/reduce conflict in a simple Yacc grammar

Tags: reduce, yacc

I'd like to know how to resolve the reduce/reduce conflict in the grammar below. The problematic rule is: LDA HASH expression -when I remove it the conflict disappears. I have tried breaking the LDA xxx parsing rules up into separate rules, but I still get a conflict. What is the problem with this rule exactly and how do I fix it?

```
%%

program:
        program statement NEWLINE               {  }
        |
        ;

statement:
        instruction                             {
                                                    printf("Opcode: %c Address Mode: %d Operand: %d\n", opcode[0], address_mode, operand);
                                                    numInstructions++;
                                                }
        | assignment                            { 
                                                
                                                }
        ;
        
instruction: ADC expression                     {
                                                
                                                }
            | CLC                               { 
                                                    address_mode = IMPLIED_MODE;
                                                    opcode[0] = 0x18;
                                                    fwrite(opcode, 1, 1, output);
                                                }
                                                
            | CLD                               { 
                                                    address_mode = IMPLIED_MODE;
                                                    opcode[0] = 0xd8;
                                                    fwrite(opcode, 1, 1, output);
                                                }
                                                
            | LDA expression                    {   
                                                    opcode[0] = 0xad;
                                                }

            | LDA HASH expression               {
                                                    opcode[0] = 0xa9;
                                                    address_mode = IMMEDIATE_MODE;
                                                    if( operand > 255 ) {
                                                        printf("syntax error. Immediate value too large. The value must lie in the range between 0..255. Line: %d\n", yylineno-1);
                                                        exit(1);
                                                    }
                                                
                                                }
            
            | LDA expression COMMA IDENTIFIER   {
                                                    // LDA operand, x | LDA operand, y
                                                    opcode[0] = 0xbd;
                                                }

                                                
            | STA expression                    { 
                                                
                                                }
            
            | RTS                               { 
                                                    address_mode = IMPLIED_MODE;
                                                    opcode[0] = 0x60; 
                                                    fwrite(opcode, 1, 1, output); 
                                                }
            ;

expression: number                              {   $$ = $1; 
                                                    operand = $1;
                                                    
                                                }
            | HASH number                       { 
                                                    operand = $2;
                                                }
            ;
number:
        NUMBER                                  { $$ = $1; }
        | HEXADECIMAL                           { $$ = $1; }
        | BINARY                                { $$ = $1; }
        ;

assignment:
        IDENTIFIER EQUALS expression            { $$ = $3; }
        ;
%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just spotted the error in the grammar. The problem is that the "expression: number" rule partially reduces to "HASH number" resulting in a reduce/reduce conflict with the "LDA HASH expression" rule. The way to resolve it is to delete the "HASH number" terms within the expression rule.